# Developer Mode and reduced security prompt iOS 16

Tags: ios, security, developer-program

Being an (indie) app developer and building to device on iOS 16 for the first time, I've noticed a new prompt that requires Developer Mode to be turned on with a full restart of device and the notice of reduced security.

Being an indie dev, my test phone is also my main phone. The security issue has me worried.

- Should I turn off developer mode after each install of my own test apps?
- Are there security issues I need to be aware of if I just keep developer mode on?

Answer (score 5):

This conversation st StackOverflow might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73709037/12104850

Key points (made by [paulw11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3418066/paulw11)):

- There are no additional security risks in iOS 16 developer mode than there were previously. Apple just wants you to be aware. The risk is that developer mode allows you to install apps that are not reviewed or signed by apple. It also enables other debugging features, available under developer settings that may modify the way the device behaves or provide access to data that would not otherwise be accessible
- The primary risk is untrusted code execution, still within a sandbox, but untrusted/Unreviewed could exploit some vulnerability to escape the sandbox. The risks can be exploited by anyone who has physical access to your phone and knows your passcode
- You have always had to enable developer mode, Xcode just did it for you when you connected your phone and used the "trust" process. They have just made it more explicit in ios16